# I don't have access to property in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuejs3

I ran into an error outputting the `email` property from `data()`, which prevents me from outputting to the console,

```
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    sendCreds() {
      console.log('email: ', this.form.email)
      console.log('password: ', this.form.password)
    }
  }
```

nor send it to the backend for processing, while passing the `password` property works fine. The funny thing is that I have already implemented in this way the transfer of data to the backend on the user registration page.

```
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        Username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: ''
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    sendCreds() {
      axios
        .post(REGISTRATION_API_URL, {
          name: this.form.Username,
          email: this.form.email,
          password: this.form.password
        })
        .then((response) => console.log(response))
    }
  }
```

I tried to send data to the backend server via axios in this way and expected that the data would be transferred from the forwardend to the backend, as on the registration page

```
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    sendCreds() {
      axios
        .post(API_URL, {
          email: this.form.email,
          password: this.form.password
        })
        .then((response) => console.log(response))
    }
  }
```

P.S sorry for my low skills, because it's my first project and question in StackOverflow.

Comment: why is username with capitial U?

Comment: what error do you get logging email?

Comment: I can`t withdraw email using console.log, but i can withdraw password, and i don`t understand why. I can`t only output to the console, but also send it to the server using axios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solved this trouble, as it turned out used by my custom `Form` were not need and interfered to getting `email` from `$data`.

Answer (score 0):

See this reduced test.
Console logging the expected values `this.form.email` and `this.form.password`.

```js
const {
  createApp
} = Vue

createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        email: 'test@example.com',
        password: '123'
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    sendCreds() {
      console.log('email: ', this.form.email)
      console.log('password: ', this.form.password)
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>{{ form }}</div>
  <input v-model="form.email" /><br>
  <input v-model="form.password" /><br>
  <button @click="sendCreds">sendCreds</button>
</div>
```

What error do you see? can you print out the `this.form` object and share? Any chance your `this.form.email` value becomes `undefined` after user interactions or other manipulations?

Comment: Even after copy-pasting data() and methods from your test, I couldn't display email in the console, when I tried to copy your test completely, the linter started complaining about `const { createApp } = Vue`, maybe your code is suitable for vue2?

Comment: The `const { createApp } = Vue` line was there in order to run as a standalone stackoverflow code snippet to share a workable demo. if you're using `.vue` template files as part of your app you don't need to copy the full code. Could you share more info of your problem by creating a demo or share specific screenshots and errors?